# Restore specific MSSQL backup from media set using AWS rds_restore_database

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I have backed up several Microsoft SQL Server databases to a single media set (.bak file). I have uploaded the database to S3 and am now trying to restore the database using the following script where the database is named `MyDB` and the backup media set file is `MyBackup.bak`.

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.rds_drop_database N'MyDB'
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database @restore_db_name = 'MyDB',@s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::dev-web/DbBackup/MyBackup.bak';
```

Unfortunately this just seem so to restore the first backup from the media set which is from another database. Is there a way to specify which backup I want to restore from the .bak file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems from [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Restore) that the procedure doesn't support specifying which file within a .bak you're actually trying to restore. The native [`RESTORE DATABASE` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) allows you to specify this using `FILE =` .

I think the solution in your case is to always back up any database to a single .bak file (name the backup file uniquely, and always use `WITH INIT` when backing up). Combining multiple backups into a single file doesn't have a single benefit that I can think of, especially combining multiple backups *of different databases*.

To get to the backup you want, you may have to download the multi-file backup file, restore it on your own instance using `RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH FILE =`, back that up to a new, single-backup .bak file, and upload it back to AWS. But I would consult with AWS support in case they have any other (easier) options.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but thanks for the confirmation and link to the documentation. Yeah no real benefit to combining backups into a single file.. except combining backups into a single file. I had a few databases with dependencies between them so I was backing them up together to remind me to restore them together. I also needed to upload them to S3 and thought I would be clever and just upload one file but it turns out to be a mistake and S3 handles uploading multiple files really easily anyway. I have just backed up each database one at a time now and it works fine.